What is the best way to clip (earcut) extruded geometry with two planes?
I'd like to clip or earcut the corners of an extruded mesh at a 45 degree angle so that it produces a trapezoid shape. Consider the following:
    const loader = new SVGLoader();
    const svg = loader.parse(
      `<svg width="133" height="59" viewBox="0 0 133 59" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M0 41.7655C0 41.5055 0.213699 41.2953 0.478012 41.2953C11.6691 41.3175 22.9671 42.0807 34.057 40.0509C42.9761 38.4194 51.7153 35.0789 58.9193 29.4045C61.27 27.5517 63.4351 25.4722 65.6227 23.4148C71.2801 18.0943 77.1119 12.901 83.6803 8.85257C97.8126 0.14733 116.438 -1.81604 132.376 1.55765C132.741 1.63508 133 1.95585 133 2.32087V10.3901C133 10.8215 132.646 11.1644 132.213 11.1644H120.324C119.886 11.1644 119.537 11.5128 119.537 11.9387V59.2257C119.537 59.6571 119.183 60 118.75 60H0.787316C0.348669 60 0 59.6516 0 59.2257V41.7655Z" fill="black"/></svg>`
    );
    const material = new MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: svg.paths[0].color,
      side: DoubleSide,
      depthWrite: false,
    });
    const plane1 = new Plane(new Vector3(0, 1, 1).normalize(), 150);
    const plane2 = new Plane(new Vector3(0, -1, 1).normalize(), -200);
    const planeHelper1 = new PlaneHelper(plane1, 1000, 0xff0000); // Red plane
    const planeHelper2 = new PlaneHelper(plane2, 1000, 0x00ff00); // Green plane
    scene.add(planeHelper1);
    scene.add(planeHelper2);

    const shapes = svg.paths[0].toShapes(true);
    const geom = new ExtrudeGeometry(shapes[0], {
      steps: 20,
      depth: 700,
    });
    geom.center();
    const mat = new MeshStandardMaterial({
      clipIntersection: true,
      clippingPlanes: [plane1, plane2], // Apply the clipping planes
      clipShadows: true,
    });
    const mesh = new Mesh(geom, mat);
    scene.add(mesh);

The problem with the above code is that only one of the plans clips (plane1) and plane2 deosn't affect the extrusion at all. I believe the gap of knowledge here is how to add multiple clippings that compound each other?
Also I'm not sure what the best approach is to ensure that the plane intersects the extrusion from the right angle. My current solution doesn't achieve this so it's not a properly calculated earcut.

